# Blazor Server NavManager NavigateTo cshtml

Tags: razor, navigation, blazor-server-side

I have just started on my first site using Blazor (server side).

Under normal circumstances my site navigates ok. I use a button click event to call an injected NavManager.NavigateTo while navigating between Blazor (.razor) pages.
e.g. _NavManager.NavigateTo("/mypage");   - Navigation is OK

When I try to navigate to the default login pages (cshtml)

```
_NavManager.NavigateTo("Identity/Account/Login");
```

or
_NavManager.NavigateTo("/Identity/Account/Login");

I get a message 'Sorry, there's nothing at this address.' . The browser address bar is filled in correctly. If I hit enter on the address bar then the correct page loads.

Using a <a hyperlink navigates OK.

To fix this I tried

```
_NavManager.NavigateTo("Identity/Account/Login",true);
```

this works and opens the page OK. Unfortunately if I then hit the back button it loads my original page but at the bottom of the page I get

'An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded. Reload'

when I investigate the page I get

blazor.server.js:19 [2021-03-03T14:01:43.181Z] Error: The list of component records is not valid.
e.log @ blazor.server.js:19
blazor.server.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invocation canceled due to the underlying connection being closed.

```
at e.connectionClosed (blazor.server.js:1)
at e.connection.onclose (blazor.server.js:1)
at e.stopConnection (blazor.server.js:1)
at e.transport.onclose (blazor.server.js:1)
at e.close (blazor.server.js:1)
at e.stop (blazor.server.js:1)
at e.<anonymous> (blazor.server.js:1)
at blazor.server.js:1
at Object.next (blazor.server.js:1)
at a (blazor.server.js:1)
```

I'm just wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction

Interestingly if I hit refresh, it all works Ok so I'm guessing its something (like it suggests) to do with the client dropping a connection?

Thanks

Comment: The back button on the browser has always been a problem for web developers.